# Why does jQuery.load not handle relative links?

Tags: jquery, ajax, pushstate, jquery-load

I'm using some basic jQuery to speed up my site by replacing the content via AJAX rather than fully reloading the page (similar to what [Turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/) does):

```
$("nav").delegate("a", "click", function() {
    href = $(this).attr('href');
    history.pushState(null, null, href);
    $('#main').load(href + " #main");
    return false;
});
```

The problem I'm having, though, is that the relative links on my `/portfolio` page fail. For example, I have `<img src="website.jpg">` which is located at `/portfolio/website.jpg`, but throws a 404 because `.load()` is looking for `/website.jpg`.

I know that making the image paths absolute will work, but is there some way to fix this with JavaScript? And why doesn't jQuery handle this? Are relative links bad practice?

Comment: `$('#main').load(href, " #main");` should probably be `$('#main').load(href + " #main");` if you're trying to load just part of that page into your element (but that's not what the problem in the question is).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not jQuery. `load` is loading the resource. The thing is, though, that then that *HTML* is put in your current document, and so all links within that HTML are resolved relative to the current document, *not* relative to the URL you loaded.

<s>You'll either have to make those root-relative paths, or use `get` to get the HTML and pre-process it yourself.</s>

<s>I haven't tried it, but</s> you might play with a [`base` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-base-element), dynamically adding it before doing the `load` (with the appropriate base URL derived from the `href` you're loading) and then removing it when the load is complete.

**Edit**: Yup, using `base` works:

```
$("nav").delegate("a", "click", function() {
    // *** Added var to next line
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    // *** Added base
    var base = $('<base href="' + href + '">');
    // *** Put base in head
    $("head").append(base);
    history.pushState(null, null, href);
    $('#main').contents().hide();
    $('#main').load(href + " #main", function() {
        // *** Remove base; I *think* at this point it's already
        // been used (worked in my test, anyway)
        base.remove();
    });
    return false;
});
```

Note that I added a `var` before your `href` variable. It looked like you were falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).

Comment: That's great! I didn't know we could use it like that. Cannot upvote twice unfortunately...